# How to set a limit

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

How to create a stock?

I am working on a class project, and in this project i am making a self-order interface like McDonalds. The problem in that I don't know how to create a stock, because of this reason someone can order a million burger for all they care, with my current work. From the research that I did, I found that I have to make a class for each food, then make an Arraylist. I just can't put them all together.

Please give me your advice on what to do. Here is what i have completed in my project:

```
    import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.*;
public class hg {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  InternationalFoods();
 }


 public static Component InternationalFoods() {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double nafTotal = 0, afTotal = 0, efTotal = 0, mefTotal = 0;
  String cont = "n";
  Component result = null;

  System.out.println("International Foods\nWelcome to the International Foods online ordering menu.");
  do {
   System.out.println("\nEnter the number for the corespondong menu you would like to order from:" + "\n\t1. North American\n\t2. Asian\n\t3. European \n\t4. Middle Eastern");
   int menu = input.nextInt();

   if (menu == 1) {
    //North American Menu
    int nafChoice[] = new int[13];
    String nafItem[] = {
     "Hotdogs",
     "Ribs",
     "Chicken",
     "Mashed Potatoes",
     "Classic Cheese Burger",
     "Double Bacon Cheese Burger",
     "Veggie Burger",
     "Mild Wings",
     "Hot Wings",
     "Barbeque Steak",
     "Beef Manhattan",
     "Beef Wellington",
     "Main menu"
    };
    double nafCost[] = new double[13];
    String nafAnswer = "y";
    //North American Menu
    System.out.println("Food\t\t\t\tCost\n");
    System.out.println("1.Hotdogs\t\t\t$2.99");
    System.out.println("2.Ribs\t\t\t\t$14.99");
    System.out.println("3.Chicken\t\t\t$14.99");
    System.out.println("4.Mashed Potatoes\t\t$10.89");
    System.out.println("\nBurgers");
    System.out.println("5.Classic Cheese Burger\t\t$8.99 ");
    System.out.println("6.Double Bacon Cheese Burger\t$10.99");
    System.out.println("7.Veggie Burger\t\t\t$10.99");
    System.out.println("\nWings");
    System.out.println("8.Mild Wings\t\t\t$8.89");
    System.out.println("9.Hot Wings\t\t\t$8.89");
    System.out.println("Steak\n");
    System.out.println("10.Grilled Steak\t\t$15.99");
    System.out.println("11.Beef Manhattan\t\t$15.99");
    System.out.println("12.Beef Wellington\t\t$15.99");
    System.out.println("\n13.To go back to the main menu ");
    for (int i = 0; nafAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"); i++) {
     //Ask for the user choice
     System.out.println("\nEnter a number choice from one of the options in the menu above:");
     nafChoice[i] = input.nextInt();
     if (nafChoice[i] == 1) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 2.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 2) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 14.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 3) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 14.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 4) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 10.89;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 5) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 8.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 6) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 10.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 7) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 10.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 8) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 8.89;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 9) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 8.89;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 10) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 15.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 11) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 15.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 12) {
      System.out.println(nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafCost[i] = 15.99;
     } else if (nafChoice[i] == 13) {
      break;
     } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
     }

     System.out.println("Do you want to order more from this menu?\nIf yes then please enter Y," + " if not then enter N");
     nafAnswer = input.next();
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < nafChoice.length && nafChoice[i] != 13; i++) {
     if (nafChoice[i] > 0 && nafChoice[i] < 14) {
      System.out.println(nafChoice[i] + ". " + nafItem[nafChoice[i] - 1]);
      nafTotal = nafTotal + nafCost[i];
     }
    }
   } else if (menu == 2) {
    //Asian Menu
    int afChoice[] = new int[13];
    String afItem[] = {
     "Smoked Salmon Sushi Roll(10)",
     "Spicy Tuna Sushi Roll(10)",
     "Cucumber and Avocado Sushi(10)",
     "Chow Mien",
     "Oyakodon",
     "Chinese Chicken Fried Rice",
     "Chicken Biryani",
     "Vegetarian Korma",
     "Maple Syrup Korean Teriyaki Chicken",
     "Chinese Shrimp and Tofu Soup",
     "Thai Pumpkin Soup",
     "Thai Ginger Soup",
     "Main menu"
    };
    double afCost[] = new double[13];
    String afAnswer = "y";
    //Asian Menu
    System.out.println("Food\t\t\t\t\tCost\n");
    System.out.println("Sushi\n");
    System.out.println("1.Smoked Salmon Sushi Roll(10)\t\t$4.99");
    System.out.println("2.Spicy Tuna Sushi Roll(10)\t\t$4.99");
    System.out.println("3.Cucumber and Avocado Sushi(10)\t$4.99\n");
    System.out.println("Main Dishes\n");
    System.out.println("4.Chow Mien\t\t\t\t$5.99");
    System.out.println("5.Oyakodon\t\t\t\t$5.99");
    System.out.println("6.Chinese Chicken Fried Rice\t\t$6.99");
    System.out.println("7.Chicken Biryani\t\t\t$5.99");
    System.out.println("8.Vegetarian Korma\t\t\t$5.99");
    System.out.println("9.Maple Syrup Korean Teriyaki Chicken\t$5.99\n");
    System.out.println("Soups\n");
    System.out.println("10.Chinese Shrimp and Tofu Soup\t\t$6.99");
    System.out.println("11.Thai Pumpkin Soup\t\t\t$6.99");
    System.out.println("12.Thai Ginger Soup\t\t\t$6.99\n");
    System.out.println("13.To go back to the main menu ");
    for (int i = 0; afAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"); i++) {
     //Ask for the user choice
     System.out.println("\nEnter a number choice from one of the options in the menu above:");
     afChoice[i] = input.nextInt();

     if (afChoice[i] == 1) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 2) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 3) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 4) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 5.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 5) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 6) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 5.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 7) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 8) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 5.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 9) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 5.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 10) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 11) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 12) {
      System.out.println(afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (afChoice[i] == 13) {
      break;
     } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
     }
     System.out.println("Do you want to order more from this menu?\nIf yes then please enter Y," + " if not then enter N");
     afAnswer = input.next();
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < afChoice.length; i++) {
     if (afChoice[i] > 0 && afChoice[i] < 14) {
      System.out.println(afChoice[i] + ". " + afItem[afChoice[i] - 1]);
      afTotal = afTotal + afCost[i];
     }
    }
   } else if (menu == 3) {
    //European Menu
    int efChoice[] = new int[13];
    String efItem[] = {
     "Pasta",
     "Lasagna",
     "Spaghetti and meat balls",
     "Souvlakia (Pork Kebab)",
     "Zurich Veal",
     "Italian Vegetable Soup",
     "Baklava",
     "Italian Breaded Pork Chops",
     "Greek Pasta Salad",
     "Main menu"
    };
    double efCost[] = new double[13];
    String nafAnswer = "y";
    //European Menu
    System.out.println("Food\t\t\t\tCost\n");
    System.out.println("1.Pasta\t\t\t\t$10.99");
    System.out.println("2.Lasagna\t\t\t$11.99");
    System.out.println("3.Spaghetti and meat balls\t$12.99");
    System.out.println("4.Souvlakia (Pork Kebab)\t$8.99");
    System.out.println("5.Zurich Veal\t\t\t$10.99");
    System.out.println("6.Italian Vegetable Soup\t\t$6.99");
    System.out.println("7.Baklava\t\t\t$8.99");
    System.out.println("8.Italian Breaded Pork Chops\t\t$10.99");
    System.out.println("9.Greek Pasta Salad\t\t\t$6.99");
    System.out.println("10.To go back to the main menu ");
    for (int i = 0; nafAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"); i++) {
     //Ask for the user choice
     System.out.println("Enter a number choice from one of the options in the menu above:");
     efChoice[i] = input.nextInt();
     if (efChoice[i] == 1) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 2) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 3) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 4) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 5) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 6) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 7) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 8.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 8) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 10.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 9) {
      System.out.println(efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efCost[i] = 6.99;
     } else if (efChoice[i] == 10) {
      break;
     } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
     }
     System.out.println("Do you want to order more from this menu?\nIf yes then please enter Y," + " if not then enter N");
     nafAnswer = input.next();
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < efChoice.length; i++) {
     if (efChoice[i] > 0 && efChoice[i] < 11) {
      System.out.println(efChoice[i] + ". " + efItem[efChoice[i] - 1]);
      efTotal = efTotal + efCost[i];
     }
    }
   } else if (menu == 4) {
    //Middle Eastern Menu
    int mefChoice[] = new int[13];
    String mefItem[] = {
     "Kebob (beef & chicken)",
     "Falafel",
     "Kebob roll",
     "Shawarma",
     "Hummus",
     "Lamb chops",
     "Chicken tikka",
     "Samosa",
     "Main menu"
    };
    double mefCost[] = new double[13];
    String nafAnswer = "y";
    //Middle Eastern Menu
    System.out.println("Food\t\t\t\tCost\n");
    System.out.println("1.Kebob (beef & chicken)\t$8.99");
    System.out.println("2.Falafel\t\t\t$4.79");
    System.out.println("3.Kebob roll\t\t\t$7.89 ");
    System.out.println("4.Shawarma\t\t\t$8.46");
    System.out.println("5.Hummus\t\t\t$6.77");
    System.out.println("6.Lamb chops\t\t\t$11.97");
    System.out.println("7.Chicken tikka\t\t\t$9.43");
    System.out.println("8.Samosa\t\t\t$1.25");
    System.out.println("9.To go back to the main menu ");
    for (int i = 0; nafAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"); i++) {
     //Ask for the user choice
     System.out.println("Enter a number choice from one of the options in the menu above:");
     mefChoice[i] = input.nextInt();
     if (mefChoice[i] == 1) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 8.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 2) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 3) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 4) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 5) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 6) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 7) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 8) {
      System.out.println(mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefCost[i] = 4.99;
     } else if (mefChoice[i] == 9) {
      break;
     } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
     }
     System.out.println("Do you want to order more from this menu?\nIf yes then please enter Y," + " if not then enter N");
     nafAnswer = input.next();
    }
    System.out.println("\nYour order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < mefChoice.length; i++) {
     if (mefChoice[i] > 0 && mefChoice[i] < 10) {
      System.out.println(mefChoice[i] + ". " + mefItem[mefChoice[i] - 1]);
      mefTotal = mefTotal + mefCost[i];
     }
    }
   } else if (menu < 1 || menu > 4) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    continue;
   }
   System.out.println("Would you like to proceesd to checkout? Enter 'N' to order more " + "or enter 'Y' to check out");
   cont = input.next();
  } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
  bill(nafTotal, afTotal, efTotal, mefTotal);
  input.close();
  return result;
 }
 public static void bill(double nafTotal, double afTotal, double efTotal, double mefTotal) {
  //calculate costs and output bill 
  double cost, tax, totalCost = 0;
  cost = nafTotal + afTotal + efTotal + mefTotal;
  tax = cost * 0.13;
  totalCost = cost + tax;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); //changes the amount of decimal places, from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
  System.out.println("Sub Total:\t\t$" + df.format(cost) + "\nTax:\t\t\t$" + df.format(tax) +
   "\nTotal:\t\t\t$" + df.format(totalCost) + "\nThank you for ordering from International Foods!");
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem?  "I just can't put them all together" doesn't mean much.  Also, that is a lot of code for someone to fix.

Comment: Well this is not the final work. It still needs to be edited and rechecked, i just want someone to give me ideas of how to create a stock, the codes above is to let you guys know what i am dealing with.

Comment: What do you mean "create a stock"?

Comment: @Grade11_Programmer Stackoverflow is great for dealing with specific programming errors or questions like "Why do i get Exception XYZ when i do ABC?" or "How can i shuffle a LinkedList". It isn't really the source to go to when asking very general software engineering questions to the effect of "How do i add feature X to my program?"

Comment: That is a LOT of code, and you seem to ask a question unrelated to the code. Please read "[How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @SteveSmith He means an "inventory". basicly he needs to expand his programm that there are only x items of food-1 available and that every time someone buys an item of food-1 x gets decreased and when its 0 you can no longer buy food-1.

Comment: @Andreas What do you mean a lot of code, it's only 3 methods! ;)

Comment: When i say "I want to create a stock", i mean to have  a specific number of a dish. For example, when somebody orders a dish like pasta, i don't want them ordering 50 plates of pasta. I want the limit to decrease each time they order a specific plate. When that limit reaches 0, i want a message to output the following "We are out of stock for (type of dish)" .

Comment: I assumed that you meant stock, but how does it relate to your code?  How are you storing stock levels?

Comment: Pretty much what @OHGODSPIDERS said.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was off.

Comment: So is your question "How I create a stock control system"?

Comment: @SteveSmith It's 380 lines of code. That's a lot for a StackOverflow question. Some complex questions might need that, but does the question "How to create a stock?" really need 380 lines of code to ask that?

Comment: Yes. Each time i wrote inventory, people always think it is a game or something. So i am showing my work so people don't think it is a game. Thank you.

Comment: I just want ideas on "How to create a stock", advice and ideas is all i need, maybe an example.

Comment: @Andreas That was my joke. :)  All that code in only 3 methods.

Comment: Well to most of you this is most likely a small code. But i am only in grade 11:)  That is everything i learned so it is a lot for me at the moment.

Comment: @SteveSmith Sorry, didn't recognize comment as a joke. Good one, though. :-) A 355 line method. Yikes! ◔_◔

Comment: @Grade11_Programmer: Just add a couple of int variables that hold your "stock" like `int kebobstock = 100; int shawarmaStock = 200;` then use those to keep track. decrementing those numbers and checking when they reach 0 should be doable for you. Yes it isn't pretty but any pretty solution requires knowledge in java that you yourself admit you don't have and would also require you to rewrite most of your existing program.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS When i do use these variables that you suggested, does it automatically deduct the amount of shawarma that i have in stock?

Comment: What? Of course not. You are the programmer you have to implement the logic yourself just like you had to add the logic yourself that sums up all costs to calculate the total cost.

Comment: Oh thanks. Will make a new class and do the changes you told me. will post it my results

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use third-party libraries, [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) both offer an implementation of the [`Bag`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html)/[`Multiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) collection.

Multisets seem to perfectly fit what you're trying to accomplish.

You can add burgers, take burgers away, and request the amount of burgers.

Comment: We are only learned to use simple eclipse(very basic ideas), we didn't learn to use other things, just introduction to Computer Science.